# How to gain FAT & muscle and not "lean muscle" alone, How do I get fatter?

Tags: weight-gain, body-fat

I'm currently a very skinny 59.7kg, 6'1, non-vegetarian and I want to almost double my weight to 90-100kg how can I do this over a very short(ish) period of time? (6 months)
I **don't** want to gain "Lean muscle" I just want to gain weight without all the "exercise and get lean muscle" theory.
Maybe start by changing / Tweaking my diet?

Comment: Eat lots of food and workout

Comment: Downvoting because I can't honestly imagine that many people will benefit from this discourse.

Comment: @EricKaufman people might not but I will and its not a discourse for me because I actually need to gain weight not muscle alone.

Comment: And 90-100kg is my desired weight atm.

Comment: @Malik Unless you are in the <5% body fat camp, or a physician has said you lack vitamin storage or thermo insulation, I can't really imagine a lot of people *needing* to get fatter.

Comment: I'm in a more mid(ish) range

Answer (score 3):

> Now, there are many options available for dangerously underweight individuals like yourself. I recommend a slow, steady gorging process combined with assal horizontology.
>
> You'll want to focus on the neglected food groups. Such as the Whipped group, the congealed group and the chocotastic.

[image]

> Be creative. Instead of making sandwiches with bread, use Pop Tarts. Instead of chewing gum, chew bacon.

Source: [Dr N. Riviera - Speedy Weight Gain for Underweight Individuals.](http://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/King-Size_Homer/Quotes)

Comment: And when it doubt, Play Doh is always an adequate alternative for calories.

Comment: LOL this just about fits

Answer (score 1):

Eat in a caloric surplus, meaning calculate your required calories per day to maintain your weight and then add extra calories on top of that. The more calories you eat equals the more weight you gain.

Watch the scale and adjust calories to the rate of weight gain you require.

Comment: Airtight but would my style if eating affect my weight gain? I.e If I eat a surplus in vegetables would I continue to gain weight or would I do better off with a surplus of fattier foods

Comment: calories are calories, it doesn't matter what the source is. Bodybuilders call it bulking when they want to gain extra weight, read into it

Comment: Bodybuilders who bulk hard eat everything they want. As an ectomorph(i guess) just eat everything you want, but as did Tom say make sure you go over your caloric daily needs. At that weight it should not be hard. I once met a ectomorph guy who said he drank tons of chocolate milk daily, and he trained pretty hard. He was in a pretty good shape, not fat in any ways. It is hard for you to get fat.

Answer (score 1):

Start by doing what dieting people are doing: Count your calories, eat more.

Drinking your calories might help, but avoid sodas. Milk or even beer is better in that case. Drink a gallon of milk each day and you will add weight.